# how send request from the console application to the webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I send a post request from the console application to the webapi i get a 404 error

web api controller

```
// POST: api/Intervals
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostIntervals(Intervals intervals)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Not a valid data");
            }

            _context.Intervals.Add(intervals);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
```

my model in web api

```
public class Intervals
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

this is console method

```
public class Interval
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
        }
    static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    CreateIntervalAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }

    static async Task<Interval> CreateIntervalAsync()
            {
                var intervalForTest = new List<Interval>()
                {
                    new Interval {Id = 1, DateStart = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), DateEnd = new DateTime(2018, 01, 03)},
                    new Interval {Id = 2, DateStart = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), DateEnd = new DateTime(2018, 01, 31)}
                };
                var jsonIntervalSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intervalForTest);

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                Uri uri = new Uri($"https://localhost:44323");
                var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri,
                    new StringContent(jsonIntervalSerialize, Encoding.Default, "application/json"));

if (httpResponse.StatusCode == statusCode) 
                {
                    Task delay = Task.Delay(13000);
                    await delay;
                    httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri,
                        new StringContent(jsonIntervalSerialize, Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", httpResponse);
                if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Cannot add a interval task");
                }

                var createdTask = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Interval>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return createdTask;
    }
```

Console.WriteLine("{0}", httpResponse) - this command print 404 error.
Then i try waite and again do post requests. but it give same error.
From Desktop i send json serialize object but in web api gets `PostIntervals(Intervals intervals)`-its correctly? 
How fix that?

Comment: Your `uri` variable is not pointing to the controller action, it just goes to localhost. If your code comments are correct it should be `https://localhost:44323/api/Intervals`

Comment: i try use this uri but i see same error

Comment: Then it is some other route, check how you have setup routing in the api.

Comment: I deleted everything unnecessary and the question concerns only the request post from the desktop application in webapi. Now can you see what is the problem and how fix it?

Comment: certainly part of the issue relates to what @Crowcoder mentioned, which was the route.. the other relates to where the WebApi Application is actually running.  is it `https://localhost:44323` (that port with `https`?), are you running it through IIS Express with ASP.NET self signed certificates? also, please include your entire Controller, if you have more than 1 `[HttpPost()` method defined there it would be an issue.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the controller from something like Postman?  As the others have said....  this is probably not an issue with your console app, but some routing issue with your controller.

Comment: in webapi only 1 post method and i use this route ```app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });``` . Maybe there is a problem?

Comment: your controller, it's defined as `public class IntervalsController : ApiController`  ?  could you add a simple string return method with `HttpGetAttribute` (`[HttpGet]`)  and verify in your browser that it is reachable and works at `https://localhost:44323/api/intervals`?

Comment: i make new method ```// GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        } ``` and comment method ```GetIntervals()``` (GET: api/Intervals). In bowser (https://localhost:44323/api/values) i see HTTP ERROR 404 and in fiddler it doesn't work to https://i.imgur.com/2ZNsjn1.jpg . But for when i call api/Intervals i see this value https://i.imgur.com/ir867IH.jpg

Comment: @BrettCaswell  when i post from fiddler https://i.imgur.com/NgazZZe.jpg it give 400 error(

Comment: at this point, you're reaching your endpoint.. the 400 BadRequest response is probably because you're using escaped quotes.. which is not valid json.. it essentially means `Id` field would be `Intervals."Id"`.. you escape characters when you want them to be present and not interpreted. I recommend [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) or some Json Validator tools (don't use online tools for sensitivity\PII data)

Comment: I think @Crowcoder was correct initially. And he should probably post that as an answer. Though you stated the error was the same 404, the fiddler indicates a 400 response at that endpoint (so something was improper there). probably based on the fact you're posting json of `List<Intervals>` and only have a method defined to handle `Interval`. so changes should include `Uri uri = new Uri(@"https://localhost:44323/api/Intervals");` as well as handling that consideration..

Comment: @BrettCaswell you right. i change uri, Intervals intervals to ```List<Intervals> intervals``` delete https and delete id (because set indentity is off) and result is https://i.imgur.com/y3NxrrL.jpg . the question was decided) now how to close it? there is no one answer) only discussion)